# Is it possible to call an executable's functions?

Tags: executable, libraries

I want to find out whether it is possible to circumvent an executable's gui by calling the programs internal worker methods/functions directly.

Assuming the executables are C/C++ programs with a working Gnome or KDE interfaces on Linux.

Comment: Do you have a particular one in mind? Sounds easier to work at source level. You'll probably have to get a version with debugging symbols anyway if you don't, so probably have to recompile.

Comment: This is usually not possible. Can you provide more details what you actually want to achieve? Sometimes there is a completely different way.

Comment: @ Stéphane Chazelas : no, which one is arbitrary at the moment. @jofel : The goal is to find out whether it is possible to implement a common user interface on top of multiple existing applications. If not, what would be needed to do so.

Comment: Maybe you can use [GUI automation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969062/linux-desktop-ui-automation-tool).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in special cases. What you describe is something like dynamically loading plugins via the C dynamic linking loader: try `man dlopen` for details on that. Usually the code so called has to be compiled as "position independent", so you're almost certainly out of luck for any specific program.

You could look at [userland exec](http://stratigery.com/userlandexec.html) code for some hints on how this might be done, but it almost certainly won't work to do what you describe.

Comment: Useful hints. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

*That is not tested, this is just what I would try.

So I don't know if it can count as an answer.*

If you manage to trace the excution with a debugger (this is a work of patience).
Once you have noted the addresses of the function you want to run. 
You can perhaps remote-control the debugger by the mean of a script. Beware that most applications must to go through some initialization steps first.

Something that would:

1. start debugger
2. load executable
3. set breakpoint after the application initialisation
4. run
5. jump to the function once the breakpoint is reached.

Comment: Was thinking along that way, but a debugger to regular start apps is not handy. The loader (ld-linux) is doing similar things but didn't know about the dlopen family, that @Bruce Ediger mentioned, which does the same too. Thanks guys.